# Is there any way to make withdrawn country come back?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

Including by changing save game?

I am playing normal and I am happy. Rather than replay again, I'd rather play around with my save game. First time I play I don't even know what satelite is for.

Comment: There's a fan made addon called "Long War" where they change the game a lot. Once of the changes is that you can win back lost countries. It's worth installing when you finish the original game.

Answer (score 12):

**Nope.** Once they go, it's for good.